# How can I run a command from the terminal without blocking it?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I run a lot of programs in Ubuntu from the terminal, but I would like to be able to continue using the terminal after I have a program open.  How can I put the programs in the background so that I don't have to open another window?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are different ways to run a terminal program and continue using the terminal:

- You can open another terminal tab (right-click, then select "Open New Tab").
- You can append `&` to the command you run.  Be aware that you will not see text output to the terminal, such as error messages.
- You can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and then run `bg`.  This has the same effect as running `command &`
- You can run `nohup command &` and then press enter. (Thanks to [ccpizza](https://superuser.com/users/65975/ccpizza), see comments below.)

However, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and then running your command from the GUI is usually considered best practice - there is no terminal at all!

Note that when using `&` (not `nohup`), closing the terminal **will still terminate the application unless you run `disown` afterwards**.

**EDIT:** It looks like using `nohup` will sometimes leave little droppings in your home folder.  What would normally have been logged to the terminal is apparently saved to a file in ~/.

~~

A simple way to run a program in the background is `program-name & disown`, which will drop you to a terminal which can be closed without killing the process.

Comment: To prevent killing the child process after the terminal is closed you can start your app as `nohup firefox&`.

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know that (but upon experimentation, the terminal is still "blocked")!

Comment: it is not 'blocked', it only 'looks' blocked, if you type enter once you will get a prompt.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that before.

Comment: `program-name & disown` is a nice solution

Comment: `nohup <command> &`  works perfectly, especially for remote servers where you may disconnect but want the command to keep running forever, or until it finishes.

Comment: Definitely ALT+F2 is the option to run flatpak spotify with wayland +nouveau-driver and avoid the black screen problem `flatpak run com.spotify.Client --diable-gpu`

Answer (score 11):

You can use `setsid` to run program in a new session with addition to `&>/dev/null` so you will not receive any log messages.

So it would be like

`setsid program-name &>/dev/null`

Comment: Cool. It must keep process running when user logout and current session closed.

Answer (score 8):

You can run the command with a & after.

For example:

thunderbird &

See [Here](http://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-run-commands-background-nohup-disown?lang=en) for more info.

Comment: This works only until you close the terminal window, once you close the window the program will terminate

Answer (score 3):

Using `screen` command, you can open multiple terminal sessions using a single window

`apt-get install screen (On Debian based Systems)`

`yum install screen (On RedHat based Systems)`

`screen` (start new screen)

`[Your command]`

`Ctrl+A d` to leave screen
... and so on

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

Answer (score 2):

You can run it in a virtual terminal like `tmux` (or `screen` but I heard it's not maintained anymore)

```
# This ataches your terminal to a virtual terminal
tmux
run_your_command
# This detaches your virtual terminal (previous command can be running)
CTRL-b d
run_other_commands # on your terminal
# re-attach the virtual terminal to see the status of run_your_command
tmux a
```

`tmux` can do a lot more, like :

- move your virtual terminal to another terminal
- share the virtual terminal in several terminals (other users can see what your doing ;-) )
- split the "screen" to have several terminals.
- ...

https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/